# Hyper-v number of Virtual Processor (Virtual CPU) on Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012

VMware world recommends that you only add one Virtual CPU on each Virtual Machine unless that your application requires detect more than one CPU.

Does this recommendation could be applied on Microsoft Hyper-V world? or if I requires more CPU power on a Virtual machine, should I increase the number of Virtual CPU?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

No it does not.

VMWare uses gang scheduling of virtual cores - an 8 vCPU VM waits until all eight cores can be scheduled at once. This means keeping VM vCPU counts low reduces contention between VMs each waiting on it's vCPU count of physical cores to be free.

Hyper-V schedules cores individually so this consideration does not apply.

Comment: And 2 vCPU make a lot of things snappier - IO etc., even if the application itself is only single threaded. I hardly ever use one CPU Vm's anymore.